# How can I be sure I'm buying the right KitchenAid beaters?

Tags: equipment

My daughter has a KitchenAid Architect stand mixer. Through a series of moves, she's misplaced the wire whip and the dough hook and I'd like to get her replacements.

Easier said than done! Stores don't seem to carry them. The KitchenAid website is useless. Amazon sells plenty - but they have descriptions like Tilt Head, Narrow Bowl Lift, or Wide Bowl Lift. I don't know which of these the Architect is. How can I figure out this terminology and get the right replacement beaters?

Comment: If you can, you would be best off going back there and pulling a model number from the appliance .. it's most likely on the bottom of the machine. Or finding her instruction manual, it should tell you the model on it. Doing quick a Google search, could it be this one? http://www.manualslib.com/products/Kitchenaid-Ksm150apscs-Stand-Mixer-Architect-5-Qt-712260.html

Comment: I know it's the Architect - I bought it. The question is, what do tilt head, narrow bowl lift etc **mean**? And which one is the Architect?

Comment: Umm I mean a model number. You can see on the [KitchenAid website accessories page](http://www.kitchenaid.com/shop/accessories-1/stand-mixers-3/102020102/) that accessories like this paddle: http://www.kitchenaid.com/shop/-[KFE6L]-401103/KFE6L/ will "Fits models KV25G and KP26M1X". You're looking for a model number, not a series range name. Contrast the above paddle with this paddle: http://www.kitchenaid.com/shop/-[KFE5T]-400875/KFE5T/ which "Fits models K45SS, KSM75, KSM95, KSM150PS, KSM152PS and KSM155GB." So you need a model number.

Comment: Architect is a designation name given to a particular series in that range of items. There are also Architect Dishwashers, Architect Ovens, Architect Vacuum Cleaners, all made by KitchenAid.

Comment: I bought a bowl-scraping beater not too long ago. It works perfectly with my KitchenAid purchased new about 18 years ago, but it will not work with my sister's KitchenAid purchased used at a garage sale about 15 years ago: the beater cannot be forced onto the shaft far enough to engage the little sticky-outy part that makes the beater stay on while you're mixing. The two mixers *look* completely identical. Moral of the story: make sure you keep your receipts. :)

Comment: Looking at the specs, it seems that the Architect might just be the Artisan packaged with a glass bowl.  It's a tilt-head (not bowl lift) 5qt with a 325W motor.  As it's a newer model, it's possible that there isn't the variety of incompatible model numbers like there is with the 'professional; their website only lists KSM150AGBCA.  (but because it's a new model, it's possible that accessories won't specifically list that model number even when actually compatible).

Comment: Joe, if you know for sure that these three categories are all there are, and that anything labelled tilt head will fit any KA mixer with a tilting head, then I think you have an answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, to explain the 'tilt head' vs. 'bowl lift':

On a 'tilt head' mixer, the bowl attaches with a screw motion into the base of the mixer.  The motor portion of the mixer is hinged at the back, so the front of it can be lifted up.  There's a lever to lock the head from moving on the right side (near the motor, opposite the speed control lever).  And if you don't engage it, you can make a real mess

[image: Tilt Head mixer]

On a 'bowl lift' mixer, the bowl has two little tabs on each side, which attach to two arms that protrude from roughly half way up the mixer.  The motor portion of the mixer is fixed to the stand and cannot move, instead, there's a lever on the right side of the base (near the arms) that will move the arms up and down so the bowl moves instead of the motor portion.

[image: Bowl Lift mixer]

As for narrow vs. wide ... I have no clue what the corresponding measurements are.

And I took the images from an answer from Doug that's been deleted.  If someone has pictures from the other side (showing the relevant levers), feel free to replace them.

Answer (score 0):

Measure the length and the circumference and ask for the manufacturer's. It worked for me.